# Wrong answer for missing number problem on leetcode but right answers for all testcases on c++ compiler

Tags: c++

i am doing the missing number problem. I don't understand why leetcode says: wrong answer on the input: [0,1] whereas all test cases gives correct answer on my compiler including [0,1].

You can find the question here:https://leetcode.com/problems/missing-number/

I will really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int missingNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        long long B = 0;
        int i;
        /////count element in vector////
        auto it = nums.end();
        it--;
        int xy = distance(nums.begin(), it);
        ////////////////////////////
        for(auto x : nums){
            B = B|(1<<x);
        }
        for(i=0;i<=xy;i++){
            if((B&(1<<i)) == 0){//first bit not set(skip bit 0) - bits represent array indices
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: please add a link to the leetcode question.

Comment: The numbers can be as large as 10000. That's far more than the number of bits in a `long long`. (And you found a *very* roundabout way of determining `nums.size()`.)

Comment: Your compiler should warn you that the function does not return a value on all paths, and you're always failing to notice when the largest number is missing, which will take the path that doesn't return a value, and that has undefined behaviour, which is why the function appears to work on your machine.

Comment: @0xff the link is there now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing those complex bit manipulation, you could do something like this.
As the array starts from 0 to n, you can calculate the sum of all elements from 0 to n using arithmetic progressions formula for sum.

Now, traverse the array and add up all elements. Subtract this sum from the calculated sum and you'll get the missing number

```
    int missingNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        //use arithmetic progressions formula
        //as the array always starts from zero
        //we can take n as nums.size() including the missing number
        int n = nums.size();
        int sum = (n*(n+1))/2;
        
        //traverse the array and find the sum
        int arrSum = 0;
        for(auto it : nums){
            arrSum += it;
        }
        
        //return the sum - arrSum; it gives the missing element
        return sum - arrSum;
    }
```